# Как сделать вставку в temporary через jdbc

Tags: oracle, jdbc, java

Пишу через *JDBC* посредством хранимки в  таблицу, все нормально. Решил перевести таблицу в temporary - пусто, проверял - вторая сессия не создается, но в таблицах пусто (конечно проверял из той же сессии). Может есть какая-то особенность работы с global temporary через jdbc?

---

редактирование:
хотя jdbc тут явно не при чем, тут к pl/sql вопросы

Comment: @Chupa, Если вы нашли ответ, думаю все будет полезно его узнать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2 Expert...

Ответ-то я нашел, но мне стыдно в этом признаться)))

кароче при создании таблиц забыл выставить ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS в связи с чем при коммите записи удалялись (по умолчания выставляется ON COMMIT DELETE ROWS)